# Why is $t$ considered constant when forming the differential $\mathrm dU(q_l; t)$ for $\mathrm dU= \overline{\mathrm dw}$ to be true?

Tags: classical-mechanics, work

> The definition of work function on the basis of $$U:= U(q_1,q_2,\ldots,q_n)\tag{17.6}$$ is too restricted. We have forces in nature which are derivable from a *time-dependent* work function $U(q_1,q_2,\ldots,q_n; \,t)\,.$ the equation $$\overline{\mathrm dw} = \mathrm dU\tag{17.5}$$ still holds, with the understanding that in forming the differential $\mathrm dU$ the **time $t$ is considered as a constant**.

This is excerpted from *the Principles of Variational Mechanics*' *Work Function and generalised force* by *Cornelius Lanczos*; the author mentions that for $\overline{\mathrm dw}= \mathrm dU$ to be true, the time $t$ must be considered constant while forming $\mathrm dU\,.$

I couldn't comprehend why Lanczos told so.

$\mathrm dU$ is defined as $$\mathrm dU ~=~ \sum_i \frac{\partial U}{\partial q_i}~\mathrm dq_i + \frac{\partial U}{\partial t}~\mathrm dt\,;$$ by telling $t$ to be considered as constant, does that mean he wants to discard the last term above?

What did he actually by telling us to keep the time $t$ constant? Why is that required for $\overline{\mathrm dw}= \mathrm dU$ to be true for the case of  *time-dependent* work function $U\,?$

I discussed that in the chat where [John Rennie](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/1325/john-rennie) mentioned these:

> I would guess Lanczos just means you can foliate this space into $n$ dimensional subspaces of constant $t$
>
> Within each subspace dU/dt is zero because we've defined that subspace to have constant $t.$

I still didn't get what is the point of doing all these.

Could anyone explain what he meant by saying to keep $t$ constant and why it is required for $(17.5)$ to be true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The differential form $\delta w$ for infinitesimal work (I switched notation because I don't want to draw that silly bar each time) is defined *on the space of Lagrangian mechanics*, i.e. the space spanned by the $(q,\dot{q})$. When you form $\mathrm{d}U$ as
$$ \mathrm{d}U = \partial_{q^i} U \mathrm{d} q^i + \partial_t U\mathrm{d} t$$
this can not be equal to $\delta w$ because the two forms live on different spaces! (Namely, the latter lives on the space spanned by $(q,\dot{q},t)$.)

The situation Lanczos considers here is one where $\delta w$ is itself time-dependent *as a form on $(q,\dot{q})$*, i.e. $\delta w(t)$, and that *at each instant $t$* we have
$$ \delta w(t) = \sum_i \frac{\partial U(q^i,t)}{\partial q^i}\mathrm{d}q^i.$$